# Ubuntu 16.04 Ethernet stopped working,

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

My Ethernet stopped working today and I'm trying to figure out why. I think it might have to do with the hardware not routing things properly, but this is just from googling around. I see the IRQ in the last command is 128 but the interrupt is 16 in ifconfig?
I'm not sure what changed when I booted up my laptop today vs other days...
Here are some ouptuts:

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

ifconfig

```
enp0s31f6 
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:4c:c8:0c:fc:4b  
      inet6 addr: fe80::a64c:c8ff:fe0c:fc4b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:10522 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:211 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1081441 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:39277 (39.2 KB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:dff00000-dff20000 

lo    
      Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1977 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1977 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:205001 (205.0 KB)  TX bytes:205001 (205.0 KB)
wlp2s0  
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:f6:4b:a4:c1:fd  
      inet addr:158.130.232.141  Bcast:158.130.235.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: 2607:f470:6:2008:bd50:17e5:7202:aae/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2607:f470:6:2008:b49f:f232:1ab1:4b22/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::8bdf:8abe:ed6:3b53/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3980 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3542 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2883536 (2.8 MB)  TX bytes:884644 (884.6 KB)
```

dmesg | grep e100

```
[    1.255738] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.255739] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.255754] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.255938] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.498755] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.567786] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) a4:4c:c8:0c:fc:4b
[    1.567788] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.567863] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.568603] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
[   20.282924] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[  152.843694] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
[  230.675618] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[  259.153294] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
[  267.852553] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
```

lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [8086:15b7] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM [1028:06d9]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
    description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 3a
       serial: 34:f6:4b:a4:c1:fd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-36-generic firmware=31.560484.0 ip=158.130.232.141 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 memory:dfd00000-dfd01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: a4:4c:c8:0c:fc:4b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:128 memory:dff00000-dff1ffff
```

Comment: What do you mean with *stopped working*? The interface is there but has no IP address assigned.

Comment: Can I assign myself one?  I see in the network manager the reason for the disconnects is "none" or carrier-changed". https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tKWmfgttz6/ I mean stopped working because it was working yesterday and I'm not sure what changed to cause it to not work... Sorry I'm a newbie at networking issues

Comment: If you don't know which IP address to assign, then the answer is no. Configure the device for DHCP, assuming there is a DHCP server on the net, with the tool you prefer and make sure you have a link.

Comment: as I can see now you are connected over wlp (wireless network), kindly disconnect wifi and then connect with lan again